# Why importdata is not working here?

Tags: matlab, character-encoding, beyondcompare

I have two data text files with the same text content but they have different sizes. The following snapshot compares them (using Beyond Compare).

[image]

It seems that the hex content of the files is different.
The MATLAB function `importdata` reads fine the file to the left but gives the following error with the file to the right (the bigger size file):

> Unable to load file. Use TEXTSCAN or FREAD for more complex formats.

What exactly is the difference between the two files ?

How to make `importdata` work with the file to the right ?

Comment: it seems like one text file is in ascii encoding (that is 8 bits per char) while the second one is unicode (16 bits per char). try converting the big file into simple ascii and re-read it.

Comment: It works if I convert manually. But how I need to modify my code, not the input file.

Comment: try convert to ascii using e.g., [this utility](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10686-unicode2ascii).

Answer (score 1):

The problem and solution is already mentioned in the comments:

> it seems like one text file is in ascii encoding (that is 8 bits per char) while the second one is unicode (16 bits per char). try converting the big file into simple ascii and re-read it

You may see the difference already in BeyondCompare: On the left, you have an ANSI-File, on the right you have a unicode with BOM (The hex-code looks like UTF-16LE. I'm not sure, which version the BeyondCompare you used to get the screenshot. My BeyondCompare would not show 'Unicode' but 'UTF16-LE' ...).

[image]